# Double-decoding unicode in python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I am working against an application that seems keen on returning, what I believe to be, double UTF-8 encoded strings.

I send the string `u'XüYß'` encoded using UTF-8, thus becoming `X\u00fcY\u00df` (equal to `X\xc3\xbcY\xc3\x9f`).

The server *should* simply echo what I sent it, yet returns the following: `X\xc3\x83\xc2\xbcY\xc3\x83\xc2\x9f` (should be `X\xc3\xbcY\xc3\x9f`). If I decode it using `str.decode('utf-8')` becomes `u'X\xc3\xbcY\xc3\x9f'`, which looks like a ... unicode-string, containing the original string encoded using UTF-8.

But Python won't let me decode a unicode string without re-encoding it first - which fails for some reason, that escapes me:

```
>>> ret = 'X\xc3\x83\xc2\xbcY\xc3\x83\xc2\x9f'.decode('utf-8')
>>> ret
u'X\xc3\xbcY\xc3\x9f'
>>> ret.decode('utf-8')
# Throws UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode ...
```

How do I persuade Python to re-decode the string? - and/or is there any (practical) way of debugging what's actually in the strings, without passing it though all the implicit conversion `print` uses?

(And yes, I have reported this behaviour with the developers of the server-side.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`ret.decode()` tries implicitly to encode `ret` with the system encoding - in your case ascii.

If you explicitly encode the unicode string, you should be fine. There is a builtin encoding that does what you need:

```
>>> 'X\xc3\xbcY\xc3\x9f'.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('utf-8')
'XüYß'
```

Really, `.encode('latin1')` (or cp1252) would be OK, because that's what the server is almost cerainly using. The `raw_unicode_escape` codec will just give you something recognizable at the end instead of raising an exception:

```
>>> '€\xe2\x82\xac'.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('utf8')
'\\u20ac€'

>>> '€\xe2\x82\xac'.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u20ac' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)
```

In case you run into this sort of mixed data, you can use the codec again, to normalize everything:

```
>>> '€\xe2\x82\xac'.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('utf8')
'\\u20ac€'

>>> '\\u20ac€'.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
b'\\u20ac\\u20ac'
>>> '\\u20ac€'.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('raw_unicode_escape')
'€€'
```

Comment: **Whew** - don't need to use my scary thing.

Comment: Don't know how, but it worked!

Answer (score 3):

What you want is the encoding where Unicode code point X is encoded to the same byte value X. For code points inside 0-255 you have this in the latin-1 encoding:

```
def double_decode(bstr):
    return bstr.decode("utf-8").encode("latin-1").decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use this!** Use [@hop's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267019/double-decoding-unicode-in-python/#4267315).

My nasty hack: (cringe! but quietly. It's not my fault, it's the server developers' fault)

```
def double_decode_unicode(s, encoding='utf-8'):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(c)) for c in s.decode(encoding)).decode(encoding)
```

Then,

```
>>> double_decode_unicode('X\xc3\x83\xc2\xbcY\xc3\x83\xc2\x9f')
u'X\xfcY\xdf'
>>> print _
XüYß
```

Comment: Great question, by the way. A nasty situation.  I hope someone else can come up with a neater solution than `chr(ord(c))` to convert unicode to str, character by character...

Comment: `f(char) for char in string` cries for an encoding.

Comment: transforming each character of string in sequence via some function is the very definition of encoding and decoding, that's how.

Comment: @hop: naturally, but as a solution this looks ghastly. Your `.encode('raw_unicode_escape')` is much cleaner (quite aside from the fact that the unicode->str step of your solution is over six times as fast as mine).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little script that might help you, doubledecode.py --
https://gist.github.com/1282752