# Convert unicode mess to correct characters in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, encoding

I have a string such as:

```
"MÃ\u0083Â¼LLER".encoding
#<Encoding:UTF-8>   

"MÃ\u0083Â¼LLER".inspect    
"\"MÃ\\u0083Â¼LLER\""
```

What can I do to salvage such a string? Take into consideration I do not have the original data. Is this salvageable?

Comment: what should it be? can you show us `"....".inspect`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the interest. As I stated, I do not have the original data, and so have no idea. That is my problem, and I'm hoping there is a solution. The only information on the original data I have is that it was part of a php serialised object.

Comment: but it would help so see a hex representation of the string

Comment: `inspect` produces same string but with backslashes added.

Comment: yes backslashes and hex codes, for non-ascii bytes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the string was converted from utf-8 to latin-1 *twice*. Try this on some of your data and let me know if it worked:

```
require 'iconv'

def decode(str)
  i = Iconv.new('LATIN1','UTF-8')
  i.iconv(i.iconv(str)).force_encoding('UTF-8')
end

decode("MÃ\u0083Â¼LLER")
#=> "MüLLER"
```

Comment: +1 You beat me to it by about 5s. :-D See also this related question for python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267019/double-decoding-unicode-in-python

Comment: Do you have any advice on the second string `"MA\u008EEIKIAI"` which produces: `Iconv::IllegalSequence: "\x8EEIKIAI"`?

Comment: Yes it does. Not sure if that is a good or bad thing. Has been very punishing dealing with this data and I am utterly lost to the point of despair. Where do I even look for where to start with this mess?

Comment: Found out the second string should be `Mažeikiai` by searching google without the codes. So, essentially, I need to convert `\u008E` to `Ž`.

Comment: I've tried converting from every encoding in `Iconv.list` to `UTF-8` once and twice without results.

Comment: Well, thank you very much for you help anyway. This `decode` method will come in handy.

Comment: Posted new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043840/convert-u008e-to-in-ruby. Hopefully something will turn up. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I think your data contains strings with different encodings.