# Convert escaped unicode (\u008E) to accented character (Ž) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, encoding

I am having a very difficult time with this:

```
# contained within:
"MA\u008EEIKIAI"

# should be
"MAŽEIKIAI"

# nature of string
$ p string3
"MA\u008EEIKIAI" 

$ puts string3
MAEIKIAI

$ string3.inspect
"\"MA\\u008EEIKIAI\""

$ string3.bytes
#<Enumerator: "MA\u008EEIKIAI":bytes>
```

Any ideas on where to start?

Note: this is *not* a duplicate of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042608/convert-unicode-mess-to-correct-characters-in-ruby).

Comment: Then it probably should be `"MAŽEIKIAI"` and not `"Mažeikiai"`

Comment: I did say to ignore case @padde.

Comment: Yes but what i posted is the string you expect, right? I think it's easier to post the exact expected result than adding a note to ignore the case.

Comment: @Wooble not at all duplicate, and that question doesn't have any answers which even nearly begin to answer this question.

Comment: @Wooble: wrong. `ruby -e 'puts "\u008E"'` prints nothing.

Comment: @Wooble: actually it prints the ["single shift two" character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/8e/index.htm) but certainly not `Ž`.

Comment: Indeed; comment deleted. I think the problem here is that the original string was generated from garbage, not a validly-encoded Ž character (which is `\u017d`)

Comment: The problem I find, as in the link you provided @Wooble, is that under the Java section we can clearly see `Ž`. They are, in some way, closely related. What I cannot suss out, because of my inexperience with encodings, is how they are related, and how that site alone has derived `Ž` from `\u008e`?

Comment: I think you are confused with `Kernel#p`, `Kernel#puts`, `String#to_s`(or String itself), `String#inspect`. You should read the documentation of these methods. Anyway, according to your code, the `string3` contains valid sequence `MAŽEIKIAI`, what you saw and got confused at was different representation of that string.

Comment: Could you add what `string3.bytes` shows? (I think I know, but just to be sure).

Comment: Also, where does this string come from, and is this just an example of many similar problems you have or is it just the one string?

Comment: @matt I've updated with `bytes` version of string. I've had problems with a few strings and found solutions, but this particular string has been causing many problems. Primarily because there doesn't seem to be a simple answer to convert the actual data `\u008e` to `Ž`. I mean, a regex would fix this problem, so I question whether such a library exists.

Comment: @Zenph very interesting that the `Ž` character occurs on the page about the single shift two (SST) character. But i do not see how a `Ž` could become SST, only the other way round when using Java's 'toUpperCase()'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\u008E` means that the unicode character with the codepoint `8e` (in hex) appears at that point in the string. This character is the control character “SINGLE SHIFT TWO” (see the [code chart (pdf)](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf)). The character `Ž` is at the codepoint `u017d`. However it is at position `8e` in the [Windows CP-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding. Somehow you’ve got your encodings mixed up.

The easiest way to “fix” this is probably just to open the file containing the string (or the database record or whatever) and edit it to be correct. The real solution will depend on where the string in question came from and how many bad strings you have.

Assuming the string is in [UTF-8 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), `\u008E` will consist of the two bytes `c2` and `8e`. Note that the second byte, `8e`, is the same as the encoding of `Ž` in CP-1252. On way to convert the string would be something like this:

```
string3.force_encoding('BINARY') # treat the string just as bytes for now
string3.gsub!(/\xC2/n, '')       # remove the C2 byte
string3.force_encoding('CP1252') # give the string the correct encoding
string3.encode('UTF-8')          # convert to the desired encoding
```

Note that this isn’t a general solution to fix all issues like this. Not all CP-1252 characters, when mangled and expressed in UTF-8 this way will amenable to conversion like this. Some will be two bytes `c2 xx` where `xx` the correct byte (like in this case), others will be `c3 yy` where `yy` is a different byte.

Comment: I have 500k bad strings. What a nightmare! Thanks, I believe this will bring me closer to a final solution, but I have a feeling there will have to be compromises.

Comment: @Zenph I suspect you may have had trouble with Ž in particular because it is in CP-1252, you likely had a lot of other characters that were in iso-8859-1 (latin 1). CP-1252 is a superset of 8859-1.

Comment: That's correct, I believe the data was originally encoded in latin 1.

Answer (score 5):

What about using `Regexp` & `String#pack` to convert the Unicode escape?

```rb
str = "MA\\u008EEIKIAI"
puts str    #=> MA\u008EEIKIAI

str.gsub!(/\\u(.{4})/) do |match|
  [$1.to_i(16)].pack('U')
end
puts str    #=> MA EIKIAI
```

Comment: I was beginning to think `gsub` was the best option. Thanks. I'll try this out.

Comment: The *only* problem with this is my string doesn't appear to have the unicode escaped. I can use `inspect` to escape, but that produces `MAEIKIAI`. The literal string I am working with is `MA\u008EEIKIAI`, not `MA\\u008EEIKIAI`.

Comment: @Zenph then you don't need to escape the string at all. `String#inspect` is the 'source code' representation of the string, you can copy/paste it to your source code and Ruby happily accept it. So the `inspect` version of a string will contain leading and tailing `"`, however, the underlying string doesn't have that two characters.

Comment: I've updated my question to show the differences in the string you've presented in your answer, and the actual string I'm dealing with.

Comment: @Zenph You don't need conversion at all. `string3` contains that the String `MAŽEIKIAI` you need. `String#p` shows how you can code that in your ruby code. And `Kernel#puts` shows what exactly the String is.

Comment: @Zenph try `str = "a"; p str; puts str`, check the difference, (the `"` in `p`'s output).

Comment: That's great news, but then how do I display `MAŽEIKIAI`? Your `puts str` outputs correctly, mine does not. I'm totally confused.

Comment: @Zenph that's an issue related to the terminal. You'll need a terminal that supports Unicode display. The shell under some Linux distribution/Mac OS X should work.

Comment: @Zenph it seems that I was wrong, `\u008E` is not unicode representation of `Ž`.